# {member.name} AttributeError: module 'discord.member' has no attribute 'name'

Tags: discord.py

пытаюсь сделать рандомные сообщения при входе человека на сервер с помощью утилиты random в discord.py, но это почему-то не работает.

я пытаюсь сделать так:

```
randomwelcome = [
             f"Это птица? Это самолёт? Нет, это {member.name}!",
             f"Привет, {member.name}!"]
```

но жалуется на {member.name}
я попробовал вписать такой импорт:

```
from discord import member
```

результата не дало. помогите, пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Проблема:**

f-строка используется только в тех случаях, когда у вас уже есть готовые данные в подставляемой переменной.

В данном случае, судя по всему, `member` нигде не объявляется до момента использования в списке `randomwelcome`.

Этим импортом вы импортируете не класс участника, а только файл, содержащий класс-шаблон. Поэтому вы видите ошибку о том, что `member` не содержит определения `name`, потому что `name` - это свойство класса `discord.Member`, а вы импортировали файл `member.py` из директории с библиотекой.

```py
from discord import member
```

Названия классов в `discord-py` указываются с большой буквы, но и этот импорт вам ничего не даст, так как вы импортируете не какого-то конкретного участника сервера, а только шаблон, в который позже подставляются данные реального участника.

```
from discord import Member
```

---

**Решение:**

Уберите f-строки из списка и вместо `member` напишите `0`

```py
randomwelcome = [
             "Это птица? Это самолёт? Нет, это {0.name}!",
             "Привет, {0.name}!"]
```

Тогда в выбранную строку можно будет подставить `member` при помощи `.format(member)`:

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send(random.choice(randomwelcome).format(ctx.author))
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: сработало, спасибо огромное!!

Comment: @notgura если ответ решил вашу проблему, могу я попросить вас отметить его как решение?

Comment: вроде готово, я тут новенький, не знал, что нужно